# Order bibliography by type in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Is it possible to order my bibliography entries by the type of source it is and then by name?

EDIT:
Order by this types of sources:
[image]

Comment: By type of source?  You can do it yourself by manually changing the order.

Comment: What do you mean by "type of source"? Are references to different types somehow formatted differently? If you could provide some sample bibliography lines and how you'd like them sorted, you'd be more likely to get answers.

Comment: @Excellll Please check revised post